# Adding comand-line behaviour in custom node-module like electronjs does

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am creating a JavaScript library and I want it to be used as a command when installed with `-g` flag. Question is how could I implement such behavior. I should be able to use that as a command.

Since electron behaves in such a way I thought I could refer [electron](https://github.com/electron/electron) code but didn't get from where it is happening.

---

I've implemented following behavior

node_modules/nexam/index.js

```
module.exports = require("./lib/nexam");
```

node_modules/nexam/lib/nexam.js

```js
'use strict'

exports = module.exports;

exports.sayHello = function(){
   console.log("Hello World");
}
```

main.js

```js
const nexam = require("nexam");

nexam.sayHello();
```

Output:

```
$ node main.js
Hello World
```

---

I want to use it like this

```sh
$ npm install -g nexam
$ nexam --version
nexam v1.0.0

$ nexam --sayHello
Hello World
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to handle here.

1. Add `bin` to you `package.json` file

> ```
> "bin": {
>         "nexam": "./index.js"
>       }
> ```

2. Use [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) npm package to read cli commands. Its very easy to use. Here is a snippet from their documentation page.

> ```
> var program = require('commander');
>
> program
>   .version('0.1.0')
>   .option('-p, --peppers', 'Add peppers')
>   .option('-P, --pineapple', 'Add pineapple')
>   .option('-b, --bbq-sauce', 'Add bbq sauce')
>   .option('-c, --cheese [type]', 'Add the specified type of cheese [marble]', 'marble')
>   .parse(process.argv);
>
> console.log('you ordered a pizza with:');
> if (program.peppers) console.log('  - peppers');
> if (program.pineapple) console.log('  - pineapple');
> console.log('  - %s cheese', program.cheese);
> ```

All the best.